# Add Rows dynamically having unique input id's in td

Tags: javascript, php, html

The code below displays the 10 rows having three columns. the input id's are type_1,type_2,type_3,type_4,type_5 (and same for the rest two columns room_1 to room_5, quantity_1 to quantity_5).

```
<table id="dgsv_admin" style="width:950px; height:460px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Room</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
        </tr>
        <?php for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
        {?>

        <tr>
            <td><input id="type_<?php echo $i ?>" style="width:64px;" class="easyui-validatebox"  data-options="required:true"  /></td>
            <td><input id="room_<?php echo $i ?>" style="width:64px;" class="easyui-numberbox"  required="true" /></td>             
            <td><input id="quantity_<?php echo $i ?>" style="width:64px;" class="easyui-numberbox"  data-options="required:true" /></td>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Now My question is that I have a button ADD 5 ROWS.I want to generate the above rows dynamically each time the button is clicked and at the same time I want to handle the `id's` of the `input` like on first click the id's of first column will be type_1 to type_5 and on second click they should be type6 to type_10.

```
<button class="btn btn-success">ADD 5 ROWS</button>
```

Comment: anyway to handle it. because at the end if there are 50 rows. I have to do calculation on these input values..

Comment: Well, you can do this, but I usually don't see the need: rather then using meaningless id's for this, usually a better option is to search for the relative elements surrounding a certain one. IDs are a bit over(ab)used in javascript applications where they aren't needed. If you think you absolutely _need_ id's, usually setting them on the `tr` only, and lookup the elements in there should make it a bit simpler.

Comment: How :( i am not that good in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoudl use ajax for such process.

PHP Script:

if( isset($_POST['send_row_request']) )
{
    // process the request

```
$base_id  = $_POST['base_id'];
$_SESSION['next_request_base_id'] = $base_id + 5; // setting this for the next request.



// get the data from DB. You have already written the function for you to get
// 5 rows of DB based on a base id give,
$result_array = get_db_data($base_id);

echo json_encode($result_array)

/***
Or if you are not comfortable with JSON you can loop through array and echo them 
on each iteration
***/
```

}

And HERE is the jQuery AJAX :

$(document).ready(function(){

```
  var base_id = $('#base_id').val();
```

$('myButton').click(function(){

```
  $.ajax({
      url : 'url_to_your_php_script',
      data : ({send_row_request : 'true', 'base_id' : base_id});
      success : function(msg)
      {
        // do the stuff here and don't forgot to update base_is hidden field on the last record process
      }
  })
```

});
});

And here is a simpel HTML. Note that you should save your last row's id of your first five-records into a hidden input with the id of for example #base_id. This value also should be changed on each use click on the button.

```
<input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $base_id; ?>' id='base_id' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php session variable to dynamically create rows among page request:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isseet($_POST['your_button_id']))
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['row_id']))
        $_SESSION['row_id']=$_SESSION['row_id']+1;
    else
        $_SESSION['row_id']=1;
}
?>
<table id="dgsv_admin" style="width:950px; height:460px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Room</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
        </tr>
        <?php if(isseet($_POST['your_button_id']))
        {
            $row =$_SESSION['row_id'];
            for($i=$row;$i<=$row+4;$i++)
            {        
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td><input id="type_<?php echo $i ?>" style="width:64px;" class="easyui-validatebox"  data-options="required:true"  /></td>
            <td><input id="room_<?php echo $i ?>" style="width:64px;" class="easyui-numberbox"  required="true" /></td>             
            <td><input id="quantity_<?php echo $i ?>" style="width:64px;" class="easyui-numberbox"  data-options="required:true" /></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } $_SESSION['row_id']=$_SESSION['row_id']+4; } ?>
    </thead>
</table>
```